# Entity Type requires a primary key to be defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I have 3 model classes (`Customer, Manager, Technician`) that inherit from the base class `Person`. The `Id` key is defined in the `Person` base class.

When I try to generate a controller for the `Customer` class, an error shows up indicating that the entity type customer must have a primary key.

Here's my `Person` class:

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public int? Cin { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Phone, Required]
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public Person(int PhoneNumber, string Name, string Email = null, int? Cin = null, string Address = null)
    {
        this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.Cin = Cin;
    }

    public Person()
    {
    }
}
```

And here's my `Customer` class:

```
public class Customer : Person
{
    public List<Device> CustomerDevices { get; set; }

    public Customer(int PhoneNumber, string Name, string Email = null, int? Cin = null, string Address = null)
        : base(PhoneNumber, Name, Email, Cin, Address)
    {
    }

    public Customer() : base()
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your `id` property needs to have a setter

```
public int Id { get; }              // not work
public int Id { get; set; }         // work
public int Id { get; private set; } // also work
```

you can change class `Person`

```
public class Person
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    [EmailAddress]
    public string? Email { get; set; }
    public int? Cin { get; set; }
    public string? Address { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Phone, Required]
    public int PhoneNumber { get; set; }

    public Person(int PhoneNumber, string Name, string Email = null, int? Cin = null, string Address = null)
    {
        this.PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.Email = Email;
        this.Address = Address;
        this.Cin = Cin;

    }
    public Person()
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem in your code example is that you should add **set** to your `Id` property, so Entity Framework can *set* autogenerated id.